# Discord.js Await net.Socket connection

Tags: javascript, sockets, async-await, discord, discord.js

I'm creating a discord bot to check status of a server.
i have some problems with this code part:

```
            var text = "";
            
            var hosts = client.getHosts.all(channel.guild.id);
            hosts.forEach(function(item) {
                var sock = new net.Socket();
                sock.setTimeout(2500);
                sock.on('connect', function() {
                    text += item.name + ": ONLINE ✅";
                    sock.destroy();
                }).on('error', function(e) {
                    text += item.name + ": OFFLINE ⛔";
                }).on('timeout', function(e) {
                    text += item.name + ": OFFLINE ⛔";
                }).connect(item.port, item.ip);
            });
            
            console.log(text);
```

if i put console.log there text is equal to "". How can i await that he finish the connect before?

Comment: Did you try with `map` instead of `forEach` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop:

```js
const getStatusOfSocket = (item) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        var sock = new net.Socket();
        sock.setTimeout(2500);
        sock.on('connect', function() {
            sock.destroy();
            resolve(true);
        }).on('error', function(e) {
            resolve(false);
        }).on('timeout', function(e) {
            resolve(false);
        }).connect(item.port, item.ip);
    });
};

var text = "";
            
var hosts = client.getHosts.all(channel.guild.id);
for(let item of hosts){
    const isOnline = await getStatusOfSocket(item);
    if(isOnline) text += item.name + ": ONLINE ✅";
    else text += item.name + ": OFFLINE ⛔";
}

console.log(text);
```

Note that as I used `await`, your code should be in an async function. This can be done easily by doing:

```js
(async () => {
    const getStatusOfSocket = (item) => {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            var sock = new net.Socket();
            sock.setTimeout(2500);
            sock.on('connect', function() {
                sock.destroy();
                resolve(true);
            }).on('error', function(e) {
                resolve(false);
            }).on('timeout', function(e) {
                resolve(false);
            }).connect(item.port, item.ip);
        });
    };

    var text = "";
                
    var hosts = client.getHosts.all(channel.guild.id);
    for(let item of hosts){
        const isOnline = await getStatusOfSocket(item);
        if(isOnline) text += item.name + ": ONLINE ✅";
        else text += item.name + ": OFFLINE ⛔";
    }

    console.log(text);
})();
```